# Highcharts missing even months on x-axis

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am usig x-axis type:datetime and  pointInterval:month but the default plot of highcharts missing even months like feb,apr,jun... on x-axis.

```
var series1Data = { name: 'Airtel',
                    xAxis:0,
                    pointStart: Date.UTC(2018, 0, 1),

                     pointIntervalUnit: 'month',

                    labels:{
                        step:1
                    }
```

I tried labels step:1 but it is not working.
[image]

these are my x-axis plot options

```
xAxis = [{
                        id: 0,
                        type: 'datetime',

                        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                            month: '%b \'%y'

                        },


                        labels:{
                            step:1
                        }
```

and i tried max: and ordinal:false both are not working any solution is appreciated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force highcharts to always show every month on a datetime axis you can use the `unit` declaration.

You would set the following xAxis options:

```
xAxis: {
  units: [
    ['month', [1]]
  ],
  ...
}
```

> Datetime axis only. An array determining what time intervals the ticks are allowed to fall on. Each array item is an array where the first value is the time unit and the second value another array of allowed multiples.

**API on units:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.units